# What does <<< mean in bash (ie. in socat ... <<<"string" >output-filename)

Tags: bash, socat

I am trying to understand a codebase where I see a line like below:
`socat /tmp/haproxy - <<< "show servers state" > /var/state/haproxy/global`

What is socat doing here? What does `<<<` mean?

Comment: `<<<` refer to here-strings feature of bash(it provides a string input inline to the command) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `socat` command creates a bidirectional pipe between the file `/tmp/haproxy` and `stdin` which is expressed by passing `-` to `socat`.

In fact it appends stdin to `/tmp/haproxy` and writes the resulting output to `/var/state/haproxy/global`

`<<<` is a bash feature, a so called [*here string*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings). It passes the string "show server state" as stdin to `socat`.

Answer (score 1):

A posix shell version would be:

```
echo "show servers state" | socat /tmp/haproxy - > /var/state/haproxy/global
```

`<<<` is a bashism to put a string on stdin

Answer (score 0):

The `man` pages of the `socat` command and `bash` may help (Note that `<<<` is a bash feature)

Try:

```
man socat
man bash
# Type the following when the bash man page is open
# it will point you right to the explanation of <<<
/<<<
```

Comment: How will that help with the "<<<"?

Comment: How does reading the bash and socat man pages help in understandig `<<<`?

Comment: Did you type the second two commands?  Because it directs you right to the official bash page explaining here strings.

Comment: @mut3 I'm sitting on the fence here. Sure it is a kind of an answer and points to the solution of the problem but usually you need to show more effort when answering a question on SO. If you think it is too silly for you, then don't answer.

Comment: This answer is far more helpful in the long term then going into each of those documents and just copying the text out which would not have been that much extra effort on my part.

Comment: Nope, I disagree. Without my further explanation, it is even hard to get what you mean with /<<<.. Sorry, I'm a long time vim, less, more user but it took me a few seconds. Users which are not familiar to that might not get it at all. It's just a lazy RTFM post.

Comment: I see, but in your post you reply that here strings feed to STDIN.  You're expecting someone that doesn't know how to use man pages to know what STDIN is.  My solution guides him to a document and teaches to search.  It also points to a far more comprehensive set of documentation, and years from now when <<< no longer feeds to standard input, will explain to future readers of this post in the next context.  Telling someone to read the manual for a specific coding example is bad.  Telling them where the manual is when they're asking broad entry level questions is good.

Comment: I see your point and I'm also often point to man pages. Duplicating their content here makes mostly no sense, you are right with that. Especially since they may change over time. However, this was bit too less, imho..